# The Witcher 3: On a new game, will I have to pay for the Enchanter of Runes max level, again?

Tags: the-witcher-3

If I start the new game plus in Witcher 3, will I need to pay again for the enchanter of runes to reach the maximum level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to pay again.

But the money you already have carries over to New Game Plus. I found that I had plenty of money to pay.

Comment: I paid the last level and just before start ng+. Waste of money...
Thanks!